# How to create custom UI for Azure QnA Bot in react?

Tags: reactjs, azure, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I am working on an application where I have created and published a QnA chatbot on Azure. Now, I want to create a custom API using React for the QnA Bot. I have gone through documentation from microsoft regarding using of botframework-webchat package, but there is no clear code written as to how to call the Bot with out exposing secret key and by creating a token.

Can anyone please help me in here.

Comment: please take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#production-embedding-option which does not expose the Web Chat channel secret key in the client web page

Comment: React is a library to create views. For API you'll need some server side technology (e.g. c# + aspnet core)

Comment: Thiago Custodio - My bad, what I want is to develop a customized UI

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59782810/azure-web-chat-bot-token-server

Comment: Thanks a ton for this